# configure cell drawRect : custom drawRect only appears after a drag in tableView?

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller, drawrect, custom-cell

I have got a splitViewController, the destinationController is a tableViewController and I would like to control the design of the cell if a custom class "MyCell". The drawRect is called only when I drag the tableView : the red background appears only after the cell disappeared from screen and reappeared. Would you know why?

```
//in viewController.m
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    MyCell*cell = (MyCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellDetail"] ;
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    RDV *object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [[object valueForKey:@"name"] description];
    [cell setNeedsDisplay];
    [cell layoutIfNeeded];
}



//in MyCell.m
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
    [self setBackgroundColor: [UIColor redColor]];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was a bit tricky, I had to use `MyRealCell* cell = (MyRealCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];` with `forIndexPath`, this way, the contentView frame contains something, otherwise it is 0,0,0,0.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the color change doesn't show up until you scroll, but you shouldn't be using drawRect for that purpose anyway. Put the background color code in the cell's init method or in awakeFromNib.

Comment: Thanks rdelmar, the answer was tricky, I had to use `MyRealCell* cell = (MyRealCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];` with `forIndexPath`, this way, the contentView frame contains something, otherwise it is 0,0,0,0.

Comment: @Paul, what does that have to do with setting the color?

Comment: If the frame is 0,0,0,0, it draws within nothing, whereas if the contentView has a frame, the gradient color can appear.

Comment: @Paul, that's strange. There shouldn't be any difference between the cell returned by those 2 methods.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you did not register a cell with the table view. There-for

```
MyCell*cell = (MyCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellDetail"] ;
```

returns `nil`. as you can send any message to `nil` and always `nil` of `0x0` will be returned, asking for a frame returns a `CGRectZeo`.

Why dragging does make cells appear is not obvious. do you implement `tableView:cellWillAppear:` or similar?